# Why is Hedda unable to free herself from the constraints of domesticity, while Thea is able to?

Tags: character-analysis, scandinavian-languages, henrik-ibsen, hedda-gabler

In *Hedda Gabler*, there exists the character foil of Hedda and Thea. Both of the characters have entered into marriages which have inhibited them from forming a 'free' sense of self and which reduce their agency, but while Thea eventually gains the courage to leave her husband, Hedda is unable to allow herself to violate social convention. I think this may have something to do with their class difference - Thea is a member of the bourgeoisie, Hedda is of the un-landed aristocracy - but I am not too sure.

I was hoping someone might be able to provide some insight on why these two characters differ in this regard.

Also, in what way does this juxtaposition relate to the cultural context of 19th century Norway?